# Network error when posting formData in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios, multipartform-data, form-data

Network error when posting formData in react native  "0.70.5" and FLIPPER_VERSION=0.125.0

```
 const data = new FormData();
    data.append('title', title);
    data.append('description', description);
    data.append('categoryId', categoryId);
    data.append('startDate', date);
    data.append('endDate', endDate);
    
     data.append('displayImage', { 
       uri: secondImage[0].uri, 
       name: displayImage, 
       type:'image/jpeg' 
    })
```

```
    const res = await axios
      .post(`${Base_URL}/events`, data, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
          'token': JSON.parse(token)
        }
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        // handle error
      });
```

- i downgraded react native version still same isssue
- i  changed FLIPPER_VERSION from FLIPPER_VERSION=0.125.0 to FLIPPER_VERSION=0.46.0. i get the error Could not find com.facebook.flipper:flipper:0.46.0.

Comment: Remove the `content-type` header, you don't need it. What is the error message?

Comment: same error - [Error: Network Error]

Comment: Did you find the answer? Even i am facing same issue.